# mpld3 ~ Select points and get their coordinates?

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, matplotlib, mpld3

Is it possible to use mpld3 to select certain points on a graph, and then get the coordinates of those points?

For example, here you can select points with a rectangle, which dynamically updates other subplots, is there any way to get the identity of selected points into python?

http://mpld3.github.io/examples/linked_brush.html

[image]

Comment: It is possible, but it is not simple. Here is an example of a hacky way to move information from the data viz back into python that you could adapt: http://healthyalgorithms.com/2014/05/20/idv-in-python-adding-text-callouts-to-a-scatter-plot-interactively-with-mpld3/

Comment: Thanks I also found another answer that gets the coordinates of a rectangle in javascript, now if I could some how get those values into Python (I am working on IPython notebook): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619698/how-to-dump-points-selected-with-the-linkedbrush-plugin-for-mpld3